# Unable to access a data track or sector on a Music CD?

Tags: audio, dvd, compact-disc

I have a November 2006 music CD Single that has 3 audio tracks and it contains a artist specific software that allows the fans to do various things. This is an advertised selling point of this version of the CD Single.

When placed in my external CD/DVD rom player attached to my laptop the usual autoplay does not kickin and double clicking on the CD/DVD icon does nothing.

In file explorer it shows the data track as an audio track (which is unable to be played) but when I create a ISO of the CD using Image Burn, and then open the Cue file in Notepad it is shown as data track.

TRACK 04 DATA
ISRC GBUM70604743
INDEX 00 11:03:26
INDEX 01 11:05:09

There must be a way of extracting the data and hopefully the program?

Comment: "autoplay" has been deprecated a long time ago for security reason. No modern OS, be it Windows, OSX or Linux, allows anything to run automatically from external media.

Comment: Have you tried an internet search about details of that spcific CD and the contained software? There were not so many of those CDs at that time and as far as I remember they mostly used tricks that violate the CD standard, therefore they don't work anymore. But these techniques has often been analyzed so I would start searching and learn what you can do on a recent PC to get access to the data.

Comment: Yes of course, I have tried everything I know which, when none worked, is why I am posting here looking for help from the experts.

Comment: What exactly, if any, have you found in a simple web search (as suggested in the previous comment) about that specific CD and its bundled software?

Comment: Nothing about this issue but the search confirms that the CD release exists and that track 4 is U-MYX. 4 Love It When You Call (U-Myx)

Comment: As I understand it, the issue maybe because the standards and manner of how Enhanced CDs were put together were in early development and modern computers, modern windows and CD drives are just unable to read them as they do not know what to do with them.

Now I want to be clear, I am not asking for anything ilegal but there must be a way to hack or gain acess to the two folders that is being reported on each CD by CDClone.